# How to give www.domain.tld its own seperate folder?

Tags: redirect, dns

I would like to try something.

I wanted to have on http://domain.tld/ a Multiuser Wordpress Install and on http://www.domain.tld/ a Link Directory.

As of now, the easiest way to go seemed like seperating www from non-www while putting the www in its own folder and haveing somewhere in the non-www version a clean redirect that in case someone opens the plain http://domain.tld, s/he would het redirected to http://www.domain.tld/ .. while users who open http:domain.tld/wp-admin would end up in the wordpress Login/Dashboard

Is there any idea you could give me how to seperate those two url's?

***SOLUTION for WHM/cPanel Server***

As I am not fond with console commands/navigation, I have used for everything WinSCP.

You might want to create a Testsubdomain if there is none.

locate this folder /var/cpanel/userdata/username where "username" is the username for the Account.

You will find several files like

- domain.tld.cache
- domain.tld
- cache
- main
- main.cache
- testsubdomain.domain.tld.cache
- testsubdomain.domain.tld

Nearly all of them need to be edited. Download them all and edit them in an editor like Notepad++ .. rename testsubdomain files to www.domain.tld and www.domain.tld.cache .. Edit www.domain.tld like this

```
--- 
documentroot: /home/USERNAME/public_html/www
group: USERNAME
hascgi: 1
homedir: /home/USERNAME
ip: XX.XX.XX.XX
ipv6: ~
no_cache_update: 0
owner: root
phpopenbasedirprotect: 1
serveradmin: webmaster@www.domain.tld
serveralias: www.domain.tld
servername: www.domain.tld
usecanonicalname: 'Off'
user: USERNAME
userdirprotect: ''
```

do the same in www.domain.tld.cache.

Edit all other files and check that you change everywhere the testsubdomain to www .....

Upload everything and well, I simply had to wait just a wee bit (30 minutes where I was still looking for a solution) and it worked perfectly!

I could use the Wordpress Plugin "Eggplant 301 Redirects" to create with the Plugin an 301 Redirect from http://domain.tld to http://www.domain.tld/ that works like a charm.

Problem perfectly solved in my opinion a perfect manner :) ... all by myself :P ... I just have to update the places where I had asked for some intel/help in the Problem solving..... Strange that I didn't got some, but maybe its just too odd :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have updated my initial Question, so that it no longer really is a question, but an answer too.

Took me quite some time, lots and lots of searching, finding breadcrumps and in the end it could have been solved already at least 4 hours ago *sigh* (In my first trys I had messed around in the DNS Entries, removed the default created entry for www and changed it from a CNAME record to an A record and that seemed to have caused the problem that my changes were not properly executed and only after I had terminated the account and recreated, uploaded the already long time edited files via SCP again, it worked) ... but in the end it is done

Thank you all for reading and I truly hope that this might help also someone else.